Webcam connector and socket ripped off. Can I do anything to repair it?
I tried to clean my MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Early 2013) and ripped the socket with the webcam connector out. Can I do anything to repair it?



I’m sorry this happened. It looks like the connector was corroded, perhaps liquid and salt. What happened is the connector ripped the trace off the logic board (and that connector itself was ripped off, but sometimes it’s a cleaner break), so you will need micro type soldering tools and skills to attempt a repair.
That part wss designed to stay mounted to the surface and only the cable slide out with a small connector moving parallel to the board and not lifted off perpendicular.
A good repair manual or more training is a must do step before trying anything else.
Apple will fix this in a flat rate repair and possibly cover it under Apple Care plus for a deductible (which would be generous since this looks to be a clear cut technician mistake or accidental damage).
We would need to understand why you chose to remove this as part of cleaning  but I’m going to assume you need a professional opinion as most cleaners would stop before removing this part if there’s visible corrosion or you know why it needed cleaning.
I would be disinclined to power up this Mac until it’s inspected since the traces look like there could be an electrical short on the board that would be powered even if you left the web camera cable detached.

Thank you very much for your helpful response. Unfortunately, I found out too late that the connector should not have been lifted vertically. Apple advised me to contact a third-party service. In the meantime, I have powered on the Mac several times without any issues. I have decided not to repair the webcam connector and instead purchase a USB camera. Is there anything I can do to prevent a potential short circuit, such as covering the exposed area with a specific type of tape or sealant? Your advice on any preventive measures would be greatly appreciated, as I want to ensure to be safe here.

Make sure nothing is loose inside the Mac. It could short anything or get wedged between the battery and case and pinch and start a fire. As long as that is always done, it probably won’t matter what contacts are exposed and you already risked a short from the bent pins and passed that test. Kapton tape is the way to cover leads or keep things from moving.
